# Hide text area from SpinBox

Tags: qt, qml

I want to hide the text area from the spin box and show only the indicators. I am using SpinBox from QtQuick Controls 1. Example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SpinBox {
        id: spinBox
        minimumValue:  37
        maximumValue: 40
        value: 38
        stepSize: 1
    }
}
```

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]

Is this possible?

Comment: You can fully customize SpinBox, or even write your own version in QML. More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.